# How to redirect to another doamin without changing url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

first of all I should tell you I have read most of questions like this at in a stackoverflow and other websites and but I am still have my problem .

*here `google.com` is just for test*

my second domain is completely different URL

```
# Turn on the Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^park.cggate.ir/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://google.com/$1 [P]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^park.cggate.ir
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://google.com/$1 [P]
```

and I have put this .htaccess file in `park.cggate.ir` directury

I want to redirect  my sub domain to another domain without changing URL but I have tried these codes:

but  these codes will change the URL I am confused I don't know what should I do

Comment: I believe this cannot be done by `.htaccess`

Comment: A rewriteRule with a proxy flag will _not_ change the visible URL. That is the idea behind proxying. So something is fishy here. Maybe you are looking at a cached result from earlier attempts?

Comment: Are you referring to the URL visible in browser, or the URLs appearing in resulting documents? As arkascha said `[P]` should not change the address bar URL, but if the page itself has hardcoded absolute URLs, it will bite you.